# linq distinct and select new query

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a query

```
var QP = (from a in QProductAllInfo select new { a.Id, a.Title, a.FullTitle}).Distinct();
```

Result is:

- 1 Ivanov Ivan
- 1 Ivanov  Ivan
- 2 Petrov  Petr
- 3 Sidorov Ivan
- 3 Sidorov Ivan

and i need result:

- 1  Ivanov Ivan
- 2 Petrov  Petr
- 3 Sidorov Ivan

Comment: Have you tried applying `Distinct` to your data source, like `from a in QProductAllInfo.Distinct()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that different Ids are always considered distinct you can try this.

I would probably write it in two querys. That way it is easy to debug and more readable. You can use `MoreLinq`.

[DistinctBy](https://morelinq.github.io/3.1/ref/api/html/T_MoreLinq_Extensions_DistinctByExtension.htm)

[Download](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/)

```
var temp = from a in QProductAllInfo select new { a.Id, a.Title, a.FullTitle}.ToList();

var result = temp.DistinctBy(i => i.Id);
```

You can also use

```
Var result = temp.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(y => y.First());
```

Comment: it is helped but i can't do code like this datagridview.datasource = result;

Comment: You can not assign an Ienumerable to a Datasource. Please google on how to assign the Ienumerable to Datasource. I am not good at ASP.net

Comment: It is not mine dude. It is Jon Skeets Brain child. I am just a user of it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have duplicates in QProductAllInfo, replacing your code by this should fix your problem.

```
var QP = from a in QProductAllInfo.Distinct() 
         select new { a.Id, a.Title, a.FullTitle };
```

if this doesn't work, you can use tuples instead of anonymous types like this:

```
var QP = from a in QProductAllInfo
         select Tuple.Create(a.Id, a.Title, a.FullTitle);
```

Applying the Distinct operator on anonymous types is useless because anonymous types are always reference types that donc implement the IEquatable interface.

Comment: in real i need select more then 8 items. and in the end i need do next: datagridview.datasource=QP;

Answer (score 0):

You could implement an IEqualitycomparer that .Distinct use to determine if the item already exist in the list. It can compare on attributes instead on the reference to the same object.

But I don't know if it works on anonymous types.